# Getting null reference exception when populating dropdown list in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I am new to ASP.Net core. I am trying to populate dropdown list in class `Createmodel` from the `Instructor` model and getting a "Null reference" exception.

This is the code in cshtml.cs file:

```
public SelectList Instructors { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var students = from s in _context.User_Profile
                   select s;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {
        students = students.Where(s => s.FirstName.Contains(SearchString));
    }

    UserProfile = await students.ToListAsync();

    var instructors = from i in _context.Instructor
                      orderby i.FirstName
                      select i;
       
    Instructors = new SelectList(instructors, "ID", "FirstName");
}
```

I have the following markup in my cshtml view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Class_Info.Instructor" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Class_Info.Instructor" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.Instructors">
         <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I am getting the error at:

```
@Model.Instructors
```

I am getting this exception
[image: This Error]

Please advise...

Comment: Do you have the line `return View(*MODEL_OBJECT*);` in your controller action? In other words, are you actually passing the model to the view? ...please show more code.

Comment: @rfmodulator: it's a Razor page - not a "classic" MVC approach - there's no separate controller. The Razor page itself acts as the controller.

Comment: @Reet: when you debug through - do you get any values in your `var instructors` ??

Comment: Can you post the directives of your .cshtml file please? Especially the `@model` directive.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you, I'm not familiar with that pattern.

Comment: @rfmodulator: then you should get acquianted ;-) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @marc_s You're right. But now I know what the razor-pages tag is for. :)

Comment: @LukeVo, I have following page directive code in cshtml file:

page
TestProject.Pages.Classes.CreateModel

{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
I had to delete the  'at' sign to reply to you .. it did not let me post.

Answer (score 2):

I had misspelled the field name here:

```
Instructors = new SelectList(instructors, "ID", "FirstName");
```

Changed it to :

```
Instructors = new SelectList(instructors, "InstructorID", "FirstName");
```

And it started working.
Thank you everyone for your help!!

Comment: I got the same, just because of miss-spelling, "ID" instead of "Id"
Solved